# Cannot fetch results with [[context executeRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am working on a new project and for that I reuse my old saving and fetching code that is working just fine in the old app. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my new project where I'm doing something very similar.

The user is presented with a table view and possibility to add new data by tapping the plus button that takes them to a different view controller where they can add the appropriate data and save.  Saving works just fine without any problems.

Here's the code that is working fine:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentContainer.viewContext;

    return context;
}
```

In main view that is table view I try to fetch the data with the following code:

```
// Fetch the data from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [MGManagedObjectContext managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Data"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; 
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

self.dataArray = [[context executeRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

For whatever reason I get the "[NSAsynchronousFetchResult mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283619220" error that I can't work out why.

Any ideas how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of method

```
- (__kindof NSPersistentStoreResult *)executeRequest:(NSPersistentStoreRequest *)request error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

use method

```
- (NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

Example:

```
self.dataArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```